# How to add credentials to jenkins without using UI?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

As part of automating my jenkins setup I need to add credentials for use with any svn configuration in my build jobs.

Manually you would add a domain to here
http://< your server >:8080/credential-store/

Then add credentials here:
http://< your server >:8080/credential-store/domain/< your domain >/newCredentials

Has anyone managed to automate this? There doesn't seem to be a usable api and the xml files contain hashed passwords which stops me from just copying
 files around (plus i worry about security with this)

Comment: I just copied the xml files directly. Not clever but it worked I guess. Maybe one day they will add a usable api

Comment: The day hasn't come so far.